# apt & aptitude segfault every time

Tags: apt, aptitude, segmentation-fault

Suddenly aptitude and apt are both bombing with segfaults; it seems to be related to the cache, as in aptitude I see the message "loading cache" before it dies:

```
Ouch!  Got SIGSEGV, dying..
```

From apt-get update:

```
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US                
Fetched 3,438 kB in 27s (125 kB/s)                                             
Segmentation fault
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'test -x /usr/bin/apt-show-versions || exit 0 ; apt-show-versions -i'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

From syslog after aptitude run:

```
Oct  8 10:28:22 etown kernel: [ 4807.432466] aptitude[5868]: segfault at 7f13ee640fc4 ip 00007f13f21180d7 sp 00007fff1d7ce6a0 error 6 in libapt-pkg.so.4.12.0[7f13f2029000+144000]
```

From syslog after apt-get update run:

```
Oct  8 11:01:48 etown kernel: [ 6814.538186] apt-show-versio[6794]: segfault at 7f56ef3cdfc4 ip 00007f56f04310d7 sp 00007ffd2bb5e060 error 6 in libapt-pkg.so.4.12.0[7f56f0342000+144000]
```

I've tried increasing the cache-limit in the conf files to no avail:

```
APT::Cache-Limit "10000000000";
```

Any ideas out there in guru-land that I might try?

Comment: Have you tried `rm -rf /var/cache/apt/*.bin`

Comment: @snoop: yes, no joy there.

Comment: try using `sudo find / -name libapt-pkg.so ` . I did not found any, but maybe you may need to reinstall it by hand, as `*.so` files are shared librarys.

Comment: @LittleByBlue: I don't see how that would relate to a segfault?

Comment: @Sagar: ah so.  well, there is no such file on my system, but there is a libapt-pkg.so.4.12 and a libapt-pkg.so.4.12.0

Comment: @Logos try to get a new `libapt-pkg.so.4.12.0` and put it where the old package is

Comment: @Sagar: okeedokee, I shall give that a try - thanks!

Comment: @LittleByBlue : Your comment led to the solution of the problem.  If you post an answer and leave a comment @ Fabby here below the question, I'll be happy to come back and upvote it! **;-)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work around found in an [ubuntu bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1445436/comments/3), requires appending a new line to `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf`:

> ```
> APT::Cache-start 200000000;
> ```
>
> This works around the issue. I don't understand why I need to tell APT to allocate more than the default amount of memory to stop it segfaulting, but I do! There's a bug here somewhere.

Many thanks to @LittleByBlue and @Sagar for pointing me in the right direction by focusing attention on `libapt-pkg.so.4.12.0`.

Comment: @fabby: I'm sure that if they are bothered they are perfectly capable of saying so themselves.  However, given that this answer is not one that was provided in their comments and is not in fact even tangentially related to either of their suggestions, it's hardly a slight.  (If _I_ were _you_, I'd actually ask potentially slighted parties *first*, **before** taking it upon oneself to speak on their behalf by lecturing someone on a rather iffy point of etiquette)

Comment: As per your request...

Answer (score 2):

The [above comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/683120/apt-aptitude-segfault-every-time#comment993403_683120) did the trick for me:

```
rm -rf /var/cache/apt/*.bin
```

If that doesn't cut it you could also try

```
rm -rf /var/cache/apt/*
```

Note that this segfaults are very specific, so this probably won't work in your case.

Comment: Tried and didn't help me... Must be system specific?